# How data is fetched from all shards in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, search, parallel-processing, data-warehouse

I have 4 nodes,3 shards and 3 replicas in Elastic search cluster. I understands that data is split and stored into the shards. **When query is requested, How data is fetched from all three shards?**

### Storage Structure :

Node 1: Shard1(Primary), Shard2(replica),Shard3(replica) 
Node 2: Shard2(Primary), Shard1(replica)
Node 3: Shard3(Primary), Shard1(replica)
Node 4: Shard2(replica), Shard3(replica)

Thanks,
Kumar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For search query, data can be searched in a primary shard or its replica shard, as Elastic never assigns the replica shard of a primary on the same data node, replica improves the high-availability also as replica contains the copy so data can be searched from replica shard as well.

But as your data is divided into 3 primary shards, so for search query at least it needs to search 3 shards(primary or primary's shard).

Comment: I understood like one request will be processed in ore more node due to shards availability is this correct?

Comment: @kumar yes, due to more primary shards which need to be queried.

Comment: Let ua consider we have 100 shards each one is there in different node. One query is requested, will 100 nodes involves here to process the query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225528/discussion-between-elasticsearch-ninja-and-kumar).